# Pandas - remove wrong entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset which has list of transition details. There are wrong entry which has same or ongoing transition date that should not happened which need to remove.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({

"Name":["A","B","C","A"],
"Dep_station":["Delhi","Bangalore","Chennai","Delhi"],
"Arr_station":["Bangalore","Chennai","Delhi","Bangalore"],
"Dep_time":["02-01-2022 10:00:00", "02-02-2022 10:00:00", "02-03-2022 10:00:00", "03-01-2022 10:00:00"],
"Arr_time":["04-01-2022 22:00:00", "04-02-2022 19:00:00", "05-03-2022 18:00:00", "05-01-2022 22:00:00"]
})
```

df looks like  this -

```
        Name    Dep_station Arr_station Dep_time    Arr_time
0   A   Delhi   Bangalore   02-01-2022 10:00:00 04-01-2022 22:00:00
1   B   Bangalore   Chennai 02-02-2022 10:00:00 04-02-2022 19:00:00
2   C   Chennai Delhi   02-03-2022 10:00:00 05-03-2022 18:00:00
3   A   Delhi   Bangalore   03-01-2022 10:00:00 05-01-2022 22:00:00
```

If you notice this A is already on travel in the date but in last row Same A is on another travel very next day. I need to remove this.

Expected output is

```
        Name    Dep_station Arr_station Dep_time    Arr_time
0   A   Delhi   Bangalore   02-01-2022 10:00:00 04-01-2022 22:00:00
1   B   Bangalore   Chennai 02-02-2022 10:00:00 04-02-2022 19:00:00
2   C   Chennai Delhi   02-03-2022 10:00:00 05-03-2022 18:00:00
```

All help and suggestion would be helpful. Thanks  in Advance.

Comment: it sounds like you want to use `df.drop_duplicates()`, but which columns do you want to check for dupes in? I see that rows 0 and 3 have the same values for Name, Dep_station, and Arr_station; do you want to remove when all those are dupes, or just some? Or are you basing this off of the time in one (or both) of Dep_time and Arr_time? But just the time, not the date as well?

Comment: i want to find it bases on departure and arrival value. in row 4 have same name , arrival and departure station but both arrival and departure are collide with row 1. as per data row is completing transition 2 days later but row 4 has departure time is on very next day.  i need to remove (row4) based on this.

Comment: are your dates dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy?

Comment: @scotscotmcc  dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Not positive if I understand the conditions correctly here, but....

If the criteria is that we want to remove rows where:

- Name, Dep_Station, and Arr_station are all the same
- Dep_time is on a date that is a single day after another entry (with matching above items)
- Dep_time is at a time that is the same as the other entry

If that's our criteria, we can sort the table in the right order and then use `df.shift()` to compare against the previous row. We will need to make sure that our Dep_time column is a datetime so we can parse the dates and times from it

```py
import datetime # this is needed to adjust dates

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name":["A","B","C","A"],
    "Dep_station":["Delhi","Bangalore","Chennai","Delhi"],
    "Arr_station":["Bangalore","Chennai","Delhi","Bangalore"],
    "Dep_time":["02-01-2022 10:00:00", "02-02-2022 10:00:00", "02-03-2022 10:00:00", "03-01-2022 10:00:00"],
    "Arr_time":["04-01-2022 22:00:00", "04-02-2022 19:00:00", "05-03-2022 18:00:00", "05-01-2022 22:00:00"]
})

df['Dep_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dep_time']) # may want to do same from Arr_time
df = df.sort_values(['Name','Dep_station','Arr_station','Dep_time'])
indexes_of_dupes = df[
    (df['Dep_time'].dt.date == df['Dep_time'].shift().dt.date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) 
    & (df['Dep_time'].dt.time == df['Dep_time'].shift().dt.time)].index
# The above has two comparisons within it: first is the comparison to on the row
# to see if the date of the row is one different (the + timedelta(days=1))
# and then to see if the time-of-day is the same
df = df.drop(indexes_of_dupes)
```

Hope this at least gets you on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `subset` parameter from `pandas.drop_duplicates`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Dep_station', 'Arr_station'])
```

Hope I get you right